# Android find current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 4 java class that i use as fragments: `F1,F2,F3,F4.
When i want to swich from one to other, i use this code:

```
android.app.FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
        F1 FP = new F1();
        FT.add(R.id.where, FP,"F1");
        FT.commit();
        FM.executePendingTransactions();
```

If i want to make possible to return from one of them to the previous, i add `addToBackStack(TAG)` as following:

```
android.app.FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
        F1 FP = new F1();
        FT.add(R.id.where, FP,"F1");
        FT.addToBackStack("F1");
        FT.commit();
        FM.executePendingTransactions();
```

I have only one activity that chages the current fragment displayed.
I would get from it, the current fragment displayed. 
I tried to write this, but `now` is always null.

```
Fragment now=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("F1");
if(now!=null && now.isVisible()) {
//some code for the current fragment
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This it may be help to you

```
 Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.where);
 if (currentFragment instanceof F1) {
       //do your stuff here
 }
```